# Formatting Sandbox

Tags: support, mathjax, editing, sandbox

The purpose of this thread is to enable people to check if their formatting works and to play around with their MathJax code.

Quoting from Bill Dubuque's [Formatting Sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666/49437) on meta.math.SE:

To use this sandbox, look for a free answer below which says "This answer is free for anyone to use". If one exists then please use it. Else create a new answer. Start writing your answer there. Be sure to save a first draft quickly, to minimize the chance that that someone else concurrently tries to use the same free answer. Then, edit it as often as you like. When you reach a point that you'd like to post it to the intended target answer, simply copy it there and post it.

When your answer is complete and you no longer need the sandbox draft, please "clear" the draft by deleting all of the text and replacing it with the text "This answer is free for anyone to use". This is important because it eliminates TeX code (which may slow down MathJax rendering).$\newcommand\dontescape{\text{This command is defined in the post body.}}$

Comment: Maybe the owner of the answers posted below should be set to [Community user](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community), so that you do not gave ping whenever someone uses the sandbox. Based on [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers#comment22087_4666), my guess is that this has to be done by someone from the SE team.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. I flagged the question for CW, but if your suggestion were implemented, that would be far better. Thanks for pointing out this possibility, I was unaware of it.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to use Benoit Schweblin's [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io). While StackEdit is designed for much more than just editing your MathOverflow posts, it supports essentially the same markdown+MathJax flavor as MathOverflow.

Comment: I will add that basic information about StackEdit can be found in [this document](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/public/res/WELCOME.md). In particular, I will stress this part: "Clearing your browser's data may delete all your local documents! Make sure your documents are synchronized with Google Drive or Dropbox."
If somebody want to look at some other editors which could be used for similar purposes, a few of them are mentioned in the answers to this question: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4735)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is free for anyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is [recent overview](https://www.sitepoint.com/best-markdown-editors-windows/) of markdown editors for windows.

I was searching for an alternative to Stackedit (which I had used for some time), simply because I missed basic file handling in the menues ("open", "save", "save as") and found, that [Typora](http://typora.io/) mentioned in the overview, fitted my bill (there are also downloadable versions).

A disadvantage of Typora is however, that **it doesn't support aligning in equations**; in that respect stackedit is superior.

A picture says more than a thousand words: one of the things I like, are the tooltips displaying a wysiwyg image of the formula you're editing.
[image: screenshot_of_Typora]

Answer (score 0):

1. $$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$
2. ${}$$$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$
    3. Test$$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$
    4. $$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$Test
    5. $$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$
3. $e^{i \pi}+1=0$
4. Test$e^{i \pi}+1=0$