# What happened to Stackedit?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for MOmeta, but as the tool had been suggested for offline editing, I'll give it a try (please vote to close if not appropriate).

Stackedit got updated in the last few days and since then it exhibits strange behavior (maybe a fault from my side as user): when using firefox, only a blank page appears in editing mode:
[image: Stackedit 5 in writing mode with Firefox]

when using the Windows explorer, then editing and WYSIWYG display aren't in sync anymore and changes are not saved:
[image: Stackedit 5 in writing mode with Windows Explorer]

have others tried the new version yet and can give hints of what goes wrong?

Comment: I will at least mention that Stackedit was recommended by François G. Dorais♦ in [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/55/formatting-sandbox/857#857) as an editor which can be used to prepare posts not directly on the MO website. (Mainly because many users might wonder whether this is related to MO in any way.)

Comment: I am not sure whether there are some other sites where something like this would be on-topic (and possibly with better chance of finding somebody able to answer). I was able to find that there is [stackedit tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackedit) on Web Applications site - but so far only 3 questions were posted with this tag.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problems you have. Do I have to somehow turn on the newer version of StackEdit that you mention? I have also asked in [Webapps.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/7/2018/1/18) whether something like this would be on-topic there. The response I got is somewhat ambivalent.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I had my browser cache and offline webpages cleaned so that the newest version of Stackedit was loaded (previously I got the message, that a new version of Stackedit is available); meanwhile I verified the behavior on my side with windows10 64bit on 3 computers and on Windows7 32bit and also with different virus scanners installed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Followup a colleage didn't observe the problem; so I completely uninstalled FireFox, reinstalled it and let it delete all saved settings; that solved the problem (with FireFox). Generally the problem only seems to appear with https://stackedit.io/app but not with https://stackedit.io/editor (the second being the "old" version).

Comment: I will just confirm that when I tried this another browser - in which I previously have not used StackEdit - I experience problems too. https://stackedit.io/editor seems to be working find, but in https://stackedit.io/app nothing gets rendered in the preview pane. Unfortunately, I do not have any good advice what could solve the problem. (Maybe reporting the problems here might be worth considering: https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues ?)